# NetSuite Custom Text Formula

Tags: case, netsuite

My first post!  We have recently implemented NetSuite and I'm working on converting some reports from our old system to NetSuite.  I love learning stuff and I do try to search first and figure it out myself but I've spent enough time on what is more than likely an easy formula for the experts.

I did get a CASE formula to work, but I don't like that every start of my fiscal year I'd have to go into it and change the years in my formula.

This is what I have that works:

```
CASE {postingperiod}WHEN 'Oct 2020' THEN 'October'WHEN 'Nov 2020' THEN 'November'WHEN 'Dec 2020' THEN 'December'WHEN 'Jan 2021' THEN 'January'WHEN 'Feb 2021' THEN 'February'WHEN 'Mar 2021' THEN 'March'WHEN 'Apr 2021' THEN 'April'WHEN 'May 2021' THEN 'May'WHEN 'Jun 2021' THEN 'June'WHEN 'Jul 2021' THEN 'July'WHEN 'Aug 2021' THEN 'August'ELSE 'Sep' END
```

I've been trying to change it to a contains, so if postingperiod contains Oct, then October, etc.

But I've tried IF(CONTAINS) to no such luck.  Here is what I've scotchtaped together from various googling...that is not working, just tried two before doing the rest of the months.

```
IF(CONTAINS({postingperiod},'Jun'),'June',IF(CONTAINS({postingperiod},'Jul'),'July',NULL))
```

I also tried a LIKE but didn't get anywhere at all.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a transaction search you can just use `TO_CHAR` in a formula (text) column:

```
TO_CHAR({accountingperiod.startdate}, 'Month')
```

You can check out the options for TO_CHAR formats at:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php